# the rules of modifying 'the/that/those'

Tags: post-modifier

(This is a situation where there is only one car in the parking lot.)

A. That car, which has a strip on its top, looks expensive.

B. That car which has a strip on its top looks expensive.

Is it at least possible to modify 'the/that/those+N' with a postmodifier even if the object is clear, since the car is at least a car which has a strip on its top?

Comment: I think you mean a stripe. That/The car with a stripe painted on the roof looks expensive.  Is this what you mean? Plural would be: Those cars with a stripe painted on the top look expensive. If this is what you mean, I will enter it as an answer.

Comment: Could you please respond?

Answer (score 0):

Both are grammatical.

First, "That" is frequently used to indicate something that is perceptible to the senses (usually sight or hearing) at a distance. Used thus, it is more specific than "the," which has no implication of being perceptible to the senses or of distance or propinquity.

If we were standing in a parking lot holding but one car. saying "That car looks expensive" would be quite natural.

We now come to the modifying clauses.

> That car, which absurdly has white tape on its roof, looks expensive.

The clause is non-restrictive. It introduces an additional thought. Spoken, such clauses are preceded and succeeded by very brief pauses. Written, they are preceded and succeeded by commas.

With respect to a restrictive clause, what would be more idiomatic in American English is to start with "The."

> The car that has white tape on its roof looks expensive.

A restrictive clause identifies which car is being discussed. It would be redundant and silly in the context of only one car in sight, but it is perfectly possible to utter nonsense grammatically. In fact, most nonsense uttered is done so grammatically.

Comment: But in the view of excepting usages never used from the grammar, can I say that the second sentence is grammatically wrong, since the grammar must show the actual usage of the natives and not show the ones that are never used or very awkward?

Comment: It is not grammatically wrong. You have contrived a situation where it would be silly to use it. If the parking lot has ten cars in it, it would not be silly. The structure is used all the time. Your book may picked an inappropriate example.

Comment: Then can I say that when there is only one object, then the structure is grammatically wrong?

Comment: We are now arguing semantics. "Every unicorn has purple hooves" is grammatical. It is also nonsense. Grammar is a matter of forms that are comprehensible. The fact that a specific form would not be used in a specific situation by anyone sane does not, in my view, make the form itself ungrammatical..

Comment: I think the question is about the commas, and I doubt he means strip. I think he means a stripe.

Comment: @Lambie I suspect you are correct, but even if “stripe” was intended,  that does not affect point that commas are used for descriptive clauses and not for restrictive ones.

Comment: The only difference between the two are the commas, so If I were you. I'd explain those two clause types.

Comment: @Lambie If the OP confirms that the only question involved comma usage, I shall modify my answer as you suggest. It would add clarity. I am not sure, however, whether or not the question also was asking about articles and demonstratives. If so, a more complex answer is required.

Comment: The OP seems disinterested.